# Adding an 'if' statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, generator

I'm trying to get a number generator to work and its going good so far, I have encountered a few problems as of lately though.  So what im trying to do is make a generator with a default string then add some numbers to the end of it.  I already have all of that figured out.  Now, I am trying to make it so that if the number my generator spits out is '5' then the next number would have to be a '1'.  Im not entirely sure if this is possible but here is my Code:

```
    public string GenerateRandomCode(int length)
    {
        string charPool = "ABCDEF1234567890";
        StringBuilder rs = new StringBuilder();
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
              rs.Append(charPool[(int)(random.NextDouble() * charPool.Length)]);
        }
        return rs.ToString();
    }

    public string Random(int length)
    {
        string charPool = "A457";
        StringBuilder rs = new StringBuilder();
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            rs.Append(charPool[(int)(random.NextDouble() * charPool.Length)]);
        }
        return rs.ToString();
    }

    public string Char(int length)
    {
        string charPool = "ABF35689";
        StringBuilder rs = new StringBuilder();
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
             rs.Append(charPool[(int)(random.NextDouble() * charPool.Length)]);
        }
        return rs.ToString();
     }

     public string Next(int length)
     {
         string charPool = "F01";
         StringBuilder rs = new StringBuilder();
         Random random = new Random();

         for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
         {
             rs.Append(charPool[(int)(random.NextDouble() * charPool.Length)]);
         }
         return rs.ToString();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       textBox1.Text = "00000001008" + Random(1) + "000" + Char(1) + Next(1) + GenerateRandomCode(15);
    }
  }
}
```

So if Char = '5' I would like to get Next to equal '1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are shooting at, but is it perhaps something like this(?):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string sRandom = Random(1);
   string sChar = Char(1);
   string sNext = "1";
   if (sChar != "5") sNext = Next(1);

   textBox1.Text = "00000001008" + sRandom + "000" + sChar + sNext + GenerateRandomCode(15);
}
```

So, whenever the method call of Char(1) returns the string "5", sNext will keep its initial value of "1". Otherwise, if Char(1) is not "5", sNext will be assigned the result of the call of Next(1).

Comment: 00000001008 - Default String | 5 - Random | 000 | 5 - Char | 0 - Next |


that is what ended up being generated

Comment: @Daktota, and what's the problem with that? I mean, if that is not what you expected, please give an example of the kind of output you expect.

Comment: @Dakota, i edited my comment while you responded. While what i said remains true, i figured it is not a good way furthering your knowledge, ahem... :)

Comment: 00000001008500051 Instead of 00000001008500050
And I understand, I just dont have the work ethic I should have

Comment: @Dakota, now i understand your comment there. You say that Next was zero. It looks to me, your button1_Click method differs from the version i posted in my answer. Please check, if your code is really identical to mine. (Note that `if (sChar != "5")` leaves no other choice than keeping `sNext = "1"` -- so obviously your code is different...)

Comment: that works double checked my code and I made a noob mistake, thanks for helping me along the way, even though Im not the smartest of people

Comment: @Dakota, well, when i started with programming (in the good days of yore(TM)), i was much dumber: I tried to type an assembly program from a book into a BASIC interpreter, and couldn't understand why it didn't work. Today i smile about it. Go figure... ;)

Comment: Sounds like something I would do xD

Answer (score 2):

Shure you can. Remember the last character and act in consequence.

```
// ...
char c = '-';
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (c == '5') {
        c = '1';
    } else {
        c = charPool[random.Next(charPool.Length)];
    }
    rs.Append(c);
}
// ...
```

`random.Next(charPool.Length)` automatically yields an integer in the range [0 ... charPool.Length-1].

Comment: I went about doing it this way, I ended up generating the number and Char came out to be a 5 but Next was a 0

Comment: I corrected my answer. I tested the index instead of the character. Now it's fixed. Sorry.